# What is the new constructor's argument rule in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm wondering why some `new` constructor has been implemented with argument and some `new` constructor has been implemented with no argument in UVM as the below example.

```
class mem_monitor extends uvm_monitor;
 
  uvm_analysis_port #(mem_seq_item) item_collected_port;
 
  // Placeholder to capture transaction information.
  mem_seq_item trans_collected;
 
  `uvm_component_utils(mem_monitor)
 
  // new - constructor
  function new (string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
    trans_collected = new();
    item_collected_port = new("item_collected_port", this);
  endfunction : new
```

As you can see in the above, `trans_collected = new();` has been implemented with no argument, and `item_collected_port = new("item_collected_port", this);` has arguments.

Is there any special rule for implementing `new` constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number (and type) of arguments passed to the `new` constructor depend on how the class was declared.  You need to refer to the IEEE 1800.2 UVM documentation.

---

`trans_collected` is of type `mem_seq_item`.  Since you did not show the class declaration of `mem_seq_item`, let's assume it was extended from `uvm_sequence_item`.  From this [online UVM document](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/index.html), we see that the constructor method for `uvm_sequence_item` is:

```
function new (string name = "uvm_sequence_item")
```

This shows that there is one argument which has a default value defined.  This means that it is not necessary to pass an argument to `new`.

Note that it is a good practice to construct a sequence item using `create` instead of `new`.  Refer to the documentation.

---

`item_collected_port` is declared as a `uvm_analysis_port`, and from the documentation, we see:

```
  uvm_analysis_port#(trans) ap;
     ap = new("ap", this);
```

We can infer that the 1st argument is a name string and the 2nd is a class handle (similar to `uvm_component`).